# Product add to compare if product out of stock

Tags: magento-1.9, out-of-stock, compare

If any product is out of stock in inventory then that's not add to compare list. But if I click `Add to Compare` button then It's show a message `The product PRODUCT NAME has been added to comparison list.`**.** Then I check my compare list that say `You have no items to compare` **.** Now I need to add product compare if that out of stock. Is it possible?

Comment: In default magento out of stock product comparisson is possible and it is default magento functionality. Pls check your default magento setup first.

Comment: Default magento not possible I checked. But now I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `addto.phtml`

```
 <?php $stock = $product->getStockItem();
if ($stock->getIsInStock()) {?>
    <?php if($_compareUrl) : ?>
        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
    <?} ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

that link should be disable if product is out of stock

Comment: That means it's impossible if product out of stock?

Comment: i didn't check on that i think it will help

Comment: It help, if I don't  want out of stock product add to compare list.

Comment: If you disable how customer add this product into compare block